# C++ library header not found

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, header, cppunit

I am OS X user and I've recently installed *"cppunit*" library using **brew**. When I try to compile "test.cpp" file using **TestCase.h** header the error occurs:

```
> test.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'TestCase.h' file not found
>     #include "TestCase.h"
```

I am compiling this file:

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "TestCase.h"

using namespace CppUnit;

class EmptyTest : public TestCase

{

};

int main()
{

}
```

Using this command:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test.x -lcppunit
```

I've also tried compiling with **-I** giving the path to the library directory but still with the same error. 
All my friends using cppunit and brew can simply include the header and the program works fine.

I would appreciate every answer.

Comment: If it works for your friends with the same steps, it seems unlikely we'll be able to diagnose it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem. I had issues with Xcode. Reinstall works fine.